# Any meaning in the grouping parens in ANTLR

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

Are the following two rules the same in ANTLR4, or does using a parens give any additional grouping information or such, similar to a regex capturing group:

```
WS  : (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')+ -> skip;

WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are synonymous.  The latter is just a more concise syntax for the former.